# Chatting with an Online Store using Langchain through APIs

Tags: e-commerce, chatbot, langchain

does anyone know of any examples or tutorials, or can offer me some tips, on how to develop a ChatBot using Langchain to enable users to navigate through an online store, interacting with the chat to choose products, via APIs? I've already developed a test using Agent and Tools that call the online store's APIs, but the interactivity wasn’t satisfying.

Thank you!